# ffmpeg convert mp4 video to rgba stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rgb, mp4, rgba

I'm looking to process the frames of an mp4 video as an rgba matrix, much like what can be done with HTML5 canvas.

This SU question/answer seemed promising: https://superuser.com/questions/1230385/convert-video-into-low-resolution-rgb32-format

But the output is not as promised. A 800KB mp4 file produced a 56MB out.bin file that seems to be gibberish, not an rgba matrix.

If anyone can clarify or provide alternate suggestions, that'd be great.

Comment: That post looks correct to me. And 54mb is a reasonable size for uncompressed video. What are you seeing that make you think it’s wrong?

Comment: @szatmary - the output is not a list of rgba integers, but seemingly random characters. If it's encoded, the format is not clear.

Comment: " but seemingly random characters" Im sure its not random. Its something. But without seeing it I cant tell you what is is. How can you be sure is not RGB values?